# getting terminal output into java

Tags: java, io, terminal, runtime, inputstream

I use the following code to get output of terminal command into my java program.

```
check = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).getInputStream()));
```

when `command = "ifconfig"` this works fine. but when `command =  "ldapwhoami -D \"cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com\" -w password"`, the variable `check` is empty. When i run the same command in the terminal myself i get the desired output. What am i doing wrong here? please help.

Comment: System.out.println("output"); ?

Comment: @Dave.Lebr1 i'm sorry i don't understand. If you mean the output when i print `check`, it prints nothing.

Comment: Did you try to use the debug mode and find what is going on?

Comment: debug mode just goes past the line. it doesn't seem like it gives any output.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping special characters in your *command* string.

If the command needs double quotes, it should be:

```
command = "ldapwhoami -D \"cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com\" -w password"
```

Note the `\"` to insert double quotes inside string.

Also try in this way:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);  
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  

String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
    System.out.println(line);  
}
```

Other option is to use `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: I'm sorry i did use it. sorry i forgot to mention it. Adjusted the Question.

Comment: @DonDrenai Ok. Try the suggestion.

Comment: Still prints nothing and the variable `in` comes out as `null`

Comment: @DonDrenai Ok, are you sure you are expecting something from standard output?. Try with `p.getErrorStream()`.

Comment: Thanks :D `p.getErrorStream` at least gives me an output. the commands supposed to return `dn:cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com` if `password` is correct and give an error if not. Still the command gives me a different error now that's not supposed to come. Anyway to do this without using process? it seems to be causing the problem